# Multi INNER JOIN gives unexpected duplicate records

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Running the following SELECT query gives unexpectedly two times the same record while there is only 1 product in the database. The are however multiple subcategories linked to the same category, but I still don't understand why this would give two results.

The ERD:

[image]

The full contents of the DB:

[image]

```
SELECT p.id AS productId, p.name AS productName FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_base AS pb ON pb.id = p.product_base_id
INNER JOIN product_category AS pc ON pc.id = pb.product_category_id
INNER JOIN product_subcategory AS psc ON psc.product_category_id = pc.id;
```

Returns:

[image]

Why is this product returned two times?

Appending `WHERE psc.id = 2` will still give one product as a result, while the intention is that this product should only be found when `psc.id = 1`.

What am I missing here? Is there something wrong with the structure? How would I get all products that have a certain subcategory?

Would I need to store `product_category_id` and `product_subcategory_id` directly in `product` as well?

Comment: Use `WHERE psc.id = 1` if that's the subcategory you want.

Comment: You're not filtering by subcategory. So you'll get as many rows as there are subcategories for the product.

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to filter out duplicates.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS productId, p.name AS productName FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_base AS pb ON pb.id = p.product_base_id
INNER JOIN product_category AS pc ON pc.id = pb.product_category_id
INNER JOIN product_subcategory AS psc ON psc.product_category_id = pc.id
WHERE psc.id = 2;`

Gives still unintentionally the product back. The intention is that this would return 0 rows, DISTINCT is not the solution.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is the solution to duplicate results, it doesn't make go from 1 to 0.

Comment: Why should `WHERE psc.id = 2` give 0 rows? It has `product_category_id = 1`, which matches the row in `product_category`.

Comment: If you use `WHERE psc.id = 3` you'll get 0 rows.

Comment: Directly putting another FK in `product` that links to `product_subcategory` in combination with DISTINCT on `product_id` does provide a solution. But I was hoping that this was not necessary.

Comment: If you don't do that, how is the application supposed to know which subcategory it is?

Comment: You don't need a FK to both `product_category` and `product_subcategory`. Since `psc` has a FK to `pc`, the FK to `psc` is all you need.

Comment: You're right. What I wanted is not possible: I need FK inside the product directly. Thank you for helping me realizing this.

Comment: It's pretty obvious why you get 2 rows.  There are 2 subcategories for category 1.

Answer (score 0):

@barmar made me realize I am simply missing a direct FK from `product` to `product_subcategory`. Otherwise there is of course a missing link between the product and subcategory.

Comment: Why would you want FK from `product` to `product_subcategory` directly.  It breaks the flow of data.  It's not a good design.

Comment: That was what my intuition was as well. How would you realize a better design though given the problem stated?

Comment: Adding a `DISTINCT` keyword will only give you one row, which is what you want, and it won't break the relationship.  I'll put it in answer since it's too long to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` will filter out the duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS productId, p.name AS productName 
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_base AS pb ON pb.id = p.product_base_id
INNER JOIN product_category AS pc ON pc.id = pb.product_category_id
INNER JOIN product_subcategory AS psc ON psc.product_category_id = pc.id;
```